# connecting a basic signal mousepress

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qcustomplot

I am using `QCustomPlot` where I am trying to write a code that will rescale my axes once the user press the mouse and drags. I did:

```
   connect(ui->plot, SIGNAL(mousePress(QMouseEvent *event)), this,  SLOT(mousedrag(QMouseEvent*)));
```

and I keep getting:

> QObject::connect: No such signal QCustomPlot::mousePress(QMouseEvent
>   *event)

But `mouseWheel(QWheelEvent*)` and both `mouseWheel` and `mousePress` have signals declared in the `QCustomPlot` library.

Where am I going wrong? Also if someone has a better signal to trigger my function `mousedrag(QMouseEvent*)` which rescales the the y2 axis according to y1 axis I am open for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signal signature passed to `connect` is invalid. The parameter names are not a part of the signature. You should also remove any whitespace so that `connect` doesn't have to normalize the signatures. A normalized signature has no unnecessary whitespace and outermost `const` and reference must be removed, e.g. `SIGNAL(textChanged(QString))`, *not* `SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString &))`.

```
                                                 remove
                                                 vvvvv
connect(ui->plot, SIGNAL(mousePress(QMouseEvent *event)), this,             
        SLOT(mousedrag(QMouseEvent*)));
```

Do the below instead:

```
// Qt 5
connect(ui->plot, &QCustomPlot::mousePress, this, &MyClass::mousedrag);
// Qt 4
connect(ui->plot, SIGNAL(mousePress(QMouseEvent*)), SLOT(mousedrag(QMouseEvent*));
```

#### Sidebar

TL;DR: This sort of API design is essentially a bug.

Events and signal/slot mechanism are different paradigms that the `QCustomPlot`'s design mangles together. The slots connected to these signals can be used in very specific and limited ways only. You have to use them exactly as if they were overloads in a derived class. This means:

1. Each signal must have either 0 or 1 slots connected to it.
2. The connections must be direct or automatic to an object in the same thread.

   You cannot use queued connections: by the time the control returns to the event loop, the event has been destroyed and the slot/functor will be using a dangling pointer.

Comment: thank you for your help I tried removing event but the problem was with whitespace in the end. Is there something I could use better then mousepress as a signal because I only want it to be activated when the user drags

Comment: @Georges The problem couldn't have been with whitespace, since that's normalized out (at a runtime cost), and your code won't work with the identifier (`event`) present. You should probably make a little test case to prove to yourself that it is so - don't merely trust me, make yourself see it. If you use Qt 5, you shouldn't be using the old `connect` syntax anyway, it'll then be compile-time checked for you.

Answer (score 0):

When using the "old" signals/slot connection syntax, i.e. the one using the `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros in the `connect()` statement, **you shall not provide the names of the parameters**, only their types.

In other words:

```
SIGNAL(mousePress(QMouseEvent *event)) // WRONG, parameter name in there!
SIGNAL(mousePress(QMouseEvent *)) // GOOD
SIGNAL(mousePress(QMouseEvent*)) // BETTER: already normalized
```

So simply change your statement to

```
connect( ui->plot, SIGNAL(mousePress(QMouseEvent*)), 
         this,     SLOT(mousedrag(QMouseEvent*)) );
```